# How to permanently save Web page modifications

Tags: html, google-chrome, safari

So I've made some little modifications to a particular website (background color, fonts, etc...) and I want these changes to be permanently applied for the next visits.
The issue is when I refresh the website, it goes back to its initial form.

Wether it's for Google or Safari web browser, is there a way to accomplish such task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that each time you enter a website your browser downloads the whole DOM code of this site. The changes you make with Chrome's or Safari's dev tools applies only for the already-downloaded DOM that is displayed on your browser, but next time you will enter the same website, a new DOM will be downloaded and displayed - without your changes.
So, actually, I'm sorry but what you want is not possible.

What you can do is:

1. Save the modified HTML code to your PC (I don't know if it helps you).
2. Use an extension that allows you to run a JS code automatically on page load (there are bunch of this kind of extensions), and with that JS code you can manipulate the DOM the way you wish to. Yea I know, that solution involves maybe long code writing but this is the way you can change the new DOM every time - automatically.